# How to get gradle to download libraries

Tags: java, gradle

I am learning Java "the hard way", meaning without any IDE. Instead, I rely on gradle and my text editor. A this moment, my project looks like this:

```
├── build.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── java
    │       └── CliOptionsTryout.java
```

Contents of build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'commons-cli:commons-cli:1.4'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Contents of CliOptionsTryout.java:

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.BasicParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.HelpFormatter;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;


public class CliOptionsTryout {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Options options = new Options();  // <=== FAILED HERE
        options.addOption("h", "help", false, "show help.");
        options.addOption("v", "var", true, "Here you can set parameter .");
    }
}
```

The project built successfully with `gradle build`, but when I executed `java CliOptionsTryout -v 100`, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/Options
    at CliOptionsTryout.main(CliOptionsTryout.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.cli.Options
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

I know that the reason is it could not find the commons-cli library. So, the question is, how do I tell gradle to download and install this library?

Comment: Use the application plugin and let gradle generate an application for you (with all the necessary dependencies, a startup script, etc.). https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html

Comment: I like @JBNizet's suggestion and it works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read the in the stack trace, the Java executable cannot find the class `org.apache.commons.cli.Options`. This class is part of a dependency you are using.

When you are executing `java CliOptionsTryout`, the Java executable looks for binaries (*.class* files in the current folder). You get an error because Gradle does not fetch dependencies (JAR files) in the folder where your `CliOptionsTryout.class` file is.

If you want to run your class with success, you need to tell the Java executable where to find the JAR file that contains the `.class` files of the library you are using.

By default, Gradle fetches all JAR dependencies in `$HOME/.gradle/...`. Your missing dependency is Apache commons CLI in version 1.4. Below is the command to locate the exact path:

```
find $HOME/.gradle -name "commons-cli-1.4.jar"
```

For instance, I get the following:

> $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.4/c51c00206bb913cd8612b24abd9fa98ae89719b1/commons-cli-1.4.jar

Once you have the path to your dependency JAR file, you can use the `java` command with the `-cp` option for extending the classpath. The classpath is used to tell where to find third-party binaries:

```
java -cp $HOME/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.4/c51c00206bb913cd8612b24abd9fa98ae89719b1/commons-cli-1.4.jar:.  CliOptionsTryout
```

In the real world, I would recommend generating a JAR file (including all dependencies) for your app and executing directly this file with `java -jar`. If you are interested in learning how to do, please have a look at the [Gradle application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html).